# sha1 hash from as3crypto differs from the one made with PHP

Tags: php, sha1, as3crypto

Make SHA1 hash from string '12345' with as3crypto in as3 the same way how it is done in there example:

```
var sha1:SHA1 = new SHA1;
var src:ByteArray = Hex.toArray("12345");
var digest:ByteArray = sha1.hash(src);
trace('SHA:' + Hex.fromArray(digest));
```

result : ec60c0fd70d82a7785f6c9a02dbe16f2e40b1344

Make SHA1 from the same string in PHP:

```
print "SHA:".sha1("12345");
```

result : 8cb2237d0679ca88db6464eac60da96345513964

If I try other tools to obtain hash I get the second result, so it looks like the result from PHP is correct.

Question: **How can I get the same hash with as3crypto?**

BTW: when testing I found that another way with as3crypto gives me another (wrong?) result:

```
var src:ByteArray = new ByteArray();
src.writeUTF("12345");
var digest:ByteArray = sha1.hash(src);
trace('SHA:' + Hex.fromArray(digest));
```

result : b98cfbc53daec4029895585ab198f7403d0d0506

Comment: This is probably due to different character encodings.

Comment: Can you not pass in a simple string in AS3? `var src = '12345'`? I'm suspecting that however those ByteArrays get stringified for the hash function, they're nothing coming out as '12345' anymore.

Comment: @MarcB - apparently not, according to the source that function only takes a byte array as input.  It's an unusual crypto library, though - most allow you to continually "update" the input stream, and then get a final digest.  This one appears to require the entire input to be in memory first and then digests it in one fell swoop.

Comment: Thanks to A. R. Younce.
It works with src.writeUTFBytes("12345");

Answer (score 2):

The hexadecimal (you're converting it with Hex.toArray) value of 12345 is not the same as the string "12345".

You are converting a **decimal number** to a **hexadecimal byte array** and hashing it, and then comparing it to a **hash of a string** generated in PHP. These will never match.

If you absolutely need to compare two hex number together then a change to your PHP like this should probably work.

> print "SHA:" . sha1(dechex(12345));

[See the dechex PHP documentation for more.](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.dechex.php)

Comment: Right, I converted it with Hex.toArray in the first example.
The problem is that in the second example (see after BTW) I do not use this function and still have wrong hash.

Comment: Are you checking the output of writeUTF to see exactly what you're hashing? I've seen suggestions that it prefixes the string with its length. See: http://symmetri.blogsome.com/2008/12/17/flex-writeutf-vs-writeutfbytes/ Try writeUTFBytes() instead.

Comment: Thanks for your help.
Now it works with src.writeUTFBytes("12345");

Answer (score 2):

The correct way to match a php sha1 using as3crypto lib is to do the following:

```
var src:ByteArray = Hex.toArray(Hex.fromString(srcString));
var sha1:SHA1 = new SHA1();
var hashedString:String = Hex.fromArray(sha1.hash( src ));
```

The first additional Hex.fromString avoids your decimal conversion as others have mentioned.

Note: The as3corelib version is much simpler: [as3corelib SHA1](https://github.com/mikechambers/as3corelib/blob/master/src/com/adobe/crypto/SHA1.as)

```
var hashedString:String = SHA1.hash( srcString );
```

Answer (score 1):

The PHP output is definitely correct.  I tested it against MySQL's `sha1` function:

```
mysql> select sha1('12345');
+------------------------------------------+
| sha1('12345')                            |
+------------------------------------------+
| 8cb2237d0679ca88db6464eac60da96345513964 |
+------------------------------------------+
```

The likely culprit is this - you're using `Hex.toArray()` on the *input* data in this line:

```
var src:ByteArray = Hex.toArray("12345");
```

When you need the original string to be in the byte array.  I don't know AS3, though, so can't answer why your second attempt also failed.

Answer (score 1):

```
var sha1:SHA1 = new SHA1(); 
var src:ByteArray = new ByteArray(); 
src.writeUTFBytes("12345"); 
trace( Hex.fromArray( sha1.hash( src ) ) );
```

using `writeUTFBytes`, this method write the string into bytesarray object without BOM.